# How calculate time from current time?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I have design an application in which i am have three text field in which i am giving my time like as 10:10 PM. Now problem is that i want to calculate time difference between current time and entered time. How calculate time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you mean by "entered time" you will most likely need to look at `NSDateFormatter` and parse the entered time into a usable form, then get a date using `NSDate` (i.e. `NSDate * now = [NSDate date];`) and do whatever math you need using the methods available in `NSDate'.

If you are just determining the difference between entered date and now this method would suit you:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceNow
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the difference in seconds using time intervals (e.g. that of the NSDate and `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`).